# Finite group existence of equivalence relation

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, equivalence-relations

I was reading about cosets and, given the fact that if $H$ is a non empty subset of a finite group G, we have the following equality $[G:H]|H|=|G|$, I came up with the following question:

If the order of a finite group $G$ is $|G|=n$, where $n$ is a composite number, and given $a,b$ positive divisors of $n$ wih $n=ab$ and $1<a,b<n$, does it always exist an equivalence relation $R$ defined on $G$ such that each equivalence class has exactly $a$ elements and there are $b$ different equivalence classes?

Comment: $[G:H]|H|=|G|$ only if $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: I think that this equality holds for any subset $H$, $[G:H]$ is the number of cosets and $|H|$ is the cardinal of $H$ as a set.

Comment: Not true. Suppose $H\subset G$ and $|H|>1/2|G|$.

Comment: You're right, I cannot define an equivalence relation of the form $aRb$ iff $ab^{-1} \in H$, reflexivity for example doesn't necessarily hold unless $e \in H$.

Comment: The word coset only really applies to sets of the form $xH$ or $Hx$ where $x\in G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can always construct such an equivalence relation by partitioning $G$ to $b$ disjoint subsets of size $a$.  There is no guarantee that this relation will be a congruence however.

Comment: So, the equivalence relation I define here is $xRy$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ belong to the same subset, right?

Comment: Right, any partition of a set induces an equivalence relation.

Comment: Thanks, now I realize my question was rather trivial, I think I need to brush up on partitions, equivalence relations and group theory!